# Error while Provisioning oracle through Puppet

Tags: oracle, vagrant, puppet

I am trying to provision Oracle through puppet. its failing while running root.sh scripts.
reason what i can see is :
/oracle/product/12.1/db/root.sh: line 13: /oracle/product/12.1/db/rdbms/install/rootadd_rdbms.sh: No such file or directory

**Error: /Stage[main]/Install_oradb/Oradb::Installdb[12.1.0.1_Linux-x86-64]/Exec[run root.sh script 12.1.0.1_Linux-x86-64]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Check /oracle/product/12.1/db/install/root_itest-525400f545bb_2016-07-28_11-32-**

49.log for the output of root script.

Skipping everything else then.

Here are the files used for provisioning

- linuxamd64_12c_database_1of2.zip
- linuxamd64_12c_database_2of2.zip

Comment: are you sure the zip files will be needed on linux , or should there be tar files

Comment: Yes it works. Provisioning other then oracle works just fine

Comment: Some kind of error I give when archive files giving by you are extracted not to the same directory. Check it again. It is common error and this point can be missed even for skilled people.

Comment: Notice: /Stage[main]/Install_oradb/Oradb::Installdb[12.1.0.1_Linux-x86-64]/File[/install/linuxamd64_12c_database_1of2.zip]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}4ed271b77b14aa25eea31b6574015471'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Install_oradb/Oradb::Installdb[12.1.0.1_Linux-x86-64]/Exec[extract /install/linuxamd64_12c_database_1of2.zip]/returns: executed successfully

Comment: Notice: /Stage[main]/Install_oradb/Oradb::Installdb[12.1.0.1_Linux-x86-64]/File[/install/linuxamd64_12c_database_2of2.zip]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}30f20ef9437442b8282ce3984546c982'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Install_oradb/Oradb::Installdb[12.1.0.1_Linux-x86-64]/Exec[extract /install/linuxamd64_12c_database_2of2.zip]/returns: executed successfully

Comment: So think both files extracted correctly.